# Finding example data to play with

Tags: r

I have started learning R. I have a basic idea about how it works. I have some really advanced, maybe overly optimistic, goals, but I am trying to start small.

I am hoping someone can point me to a website or someplace where I can find text files that have information I could play with. For example, a list of states and their education levels.

Also, if any one has some good practice projects to try, I would greatly appreciate suggestions.

Comment: Some example data sets come with R. Type `data()` to see a list and `data(AirPassengers)` to load the `AirPassengers` data (for example).

Comment: http://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/datasets/html/00Index.html ...... use library(help = "datasets") to get more info on what you are asking for

Answer (score 3):

Specifically related to your example you could look at SchoolDigger.com. It will provide you spreadsheet style tables of schools by state and that schools correlated performance by subject.

Additionally `import.io` has a lot of open data sets you could use in their Data Factory.

Answer (score 1):

[Here are a ton of datasets](http://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/datasets/html/00Index.html) that are specifically created for R.